# Can't sign into my Stack Exchange account

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this question is really relevant to this page since it doesn't really have anything to do with game development but I thought that at least the administrators of this page should know and see if they could help me. I can't talk to the administrators directly because for some reason you have to have reputation to comment on YOUR own questions. Whenever I go to the sign in page I enter my email and password and press sign in. It takes me back to the homepage still not signed in. I know I'm not entering my password wrong because it tells me when I do. The administrators were asking me why I keep using different accounts, this is why. I can't use the account I created. If anyone knows why this is let me know

Comment: Hi @RedDragon2001, next time try using the Contact Form (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/contact) for technical help with the Stack Exchange network

Answer (score 2):

sorry you're having trouble with this login system.

Ordinarily you can comment on your own questions regardless of reputation. But because you're signing in with a new account every time, the system doesn't know you're the same person, so it's unable to give you that privilege.

StackExchange has a special feature called "[unregistered accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262909/how-do-unregistered-accounts-work)," designed to make it easier for people to contribute without making a big commitment to site membership. A user can sign in with just a name and an email address, without authenticating with a password. Instead, it uses cookies to associate your browser with this temporary account. If you decide you want to stick around long-term, you can [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account), providing a password that will let you sign into the same ID from anywhere.

Every post I've seen with your name so far has been from a different unregistered account. If you're hopping around between browsers / devices, using internet cafes, or private browsing features, that might be the reason: your cookies aren't able to follow you from one session to the next, so the system is unable to verify that you're the same user.

You can solve this by [registering your current account and providing a password, then following the steps here to request merging it with your previous accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous). Then you can authenticate yourself using your login & password to sign into the same account even without the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was migrated here to meta because it was about the game dev stack exchange site rather than game development itself.

Each stack exchange site has a meta site. You can learn more about [what meta is & how it works here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta); a summarized version is:

- It's a place for Stack Exchange users to communicate with the Stack Exchange company & each other about the Stack Exchange sites.
- It functions a bit differently in terms of tags & voting.

If you have other questions about the site or questions about questions ('why is this question considered off topic', etc), this is probably the place the ask them.